# Different response if data is inputted more than once

Tags: python

I'm new to python. I am trying to create a script that gives me a different response when the same data is inputted more than once. The code goes like this :

```
def loop() :
    Repeat = 0
    response = raw_input("enter something : ")
    if response == "hi"
        Repeat += 1
        print "hello"
        loop()
        if Repeat > 2 :
            print "you have already said hi"
            loop()


def main() :
    loop()
    raw_input()

main()
```

The above code doesn't work. preferably I would like a statement that checks both conditions, but i'm not quite sure how this could be done.

Comment: You should use a while loop for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `dict` to store words/count.  You can then inquire if the word is in the dictionary and update count ...

```
words = {}
while True:
    word = raw_input("Say something:")
    if word in words:
       words[word] += 1
       print "you already said ",words[word]
       continue
    else:
       words[word] = 0
       #...
```

You could also do this with `try`/`except`, but I thought I'd keep it simple to start out...

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
def loop(rep=None):
    rep=rep if rep else set()  #use a set or list to store the responses
    response=raw_input("enter something : ")
    if response not in rep:                    #if the response is not found in rep
        rep.add(response)                      #store response in rep   
        print "hello"
        loop(rep)                              #pass rep while calling loop()
    else:
        print "You've already said {0}".format(response)    #if response is found 
        loop(rep)
loop()
```

**output:**

```
enter something : hi
hello
enter something : hi
You've already said hi
enter something : foo
hello
enter something : bar
hello
enter something : bar
You've already said bar
enter something :
```

PS: also add a breaking condition to `loop()` otherwise it'll be an infinite loop

Comment: This works and does exactly what the original seems to be trying for, but note that it is recursive.  This isn't bad per se, but python does not have tail call optimization yet (definitely on my personal wish list).  So, it will eventually hit the recursive depth limit and use up more memory than a non-recursive option.

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman recursion limit can changed using `sys.setrecursionlimit`, I totally agree with speed.(recursion are always slow).

Comment: Very true.  It's a fine answer, (upvoted), just worth pointing out that it is recursive and without tail call optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement above is recursively calling itself.  The new instance of loop does not have access to the calling value of Repeat and instead has its own local copy of Repeat.  Also, you have if `Repeat > 2`.  As written this means that it won't get your other print statement until they input "hello" three times to get the counter up to 3.  You probably want to make that `Repeat >= 2`.

What you want is a while loop that tracks whether the input is repeated.  In real life you probably want some condition to tell that while loop when to end, but you don't have whine here so you could use `while True:` to loop forever.

Finally, your code only checks if they put in "hello" more than once.  You could make it more general by tracking what they have already said instead, and get rid of the need to have a counter in the process.  For a fast sloppy version that I haven't tested, it might loop like:

```
alreadySaid = set() #sets are effecient and only store a specific element once
while True: #probably want an actual break condition here, but to do it forever this works
   response = raw_input("enter something : ") 
   if response in alreadySaid:
      print 'You already said {}'.format(response)
   else:
      print response
      alreadySaid.add(response)
```